# Mongo registration happens but passport gives me Unauthorized. Data gets stored in Mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, passport.js, web-development-server

This is the code for Registration. User.register() works properly, data gets stored in Mongodb but passport.authenticate() fails and gives me "Unauthorized"

```
router.post("/register", function(req, res){
    var age = req.body.age
    var email = req.body.email
    var dateOfBirth = req.body.dateOfBirth
    var school = req.body.school
    var department = req.body.department
    var studentClass = req.body.studentClass
    var section = req.body.section
    var password = req.body.password

    var newUser = new User({username : req.body.username, age : age, email : email, dateOfBirth : dateOfBirth, school : school, department : department, studentClass : studentClass, section : section, password : password})

    User.register(newUser, req.body.password, function(err, newUser){
        if(err){
            return res.render("registrationpage")
        }else{
        passport.authenticate("local")(req, res, function(){
            res.redirect("/schools")
        })
    }
    })
})
```

Same happens for my login code

```
router.post("/login", passport.authenticate("local"), function(req, res, err){
      console.log(err)   
      res.redirect("/")
})
```

Below are the login and registration forms

```
<form action = "/login" id = "form" method="POST" class = "form-control">
 <label for = "username" class="form-label">Username</label>
 <input type = "text"  class = "form-control" name = "username" >
 <label for = "password" class="form-label">Password</label>
 <input type = "password"  class = "form-control" name = "password" >
 <button type = "submit" class = "btn btn-outline-primary">Login</button>
</form>

<form action = "/register" id = "form" method="POST" class = "form-control">
 <label for = "username" class = "form-label">Name</label>
 <input type = "text"  class = "form-control" name = "username" >
 <label for = "age" class="form-label">Age</label>
 <input type = "text"  class = "form-control" name = "age">
 <label for = "email" class="form-label">Email</label>
 <input type = "text"  class = "form-control" name = "email" placeholder="name@email.com">
 <label for = "dateOfBirth" class="form-label">Date of Birth</label>
 <input type = "text"  class = "form-control" name = "dateOfBirth" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy">
 <label for = "school" class="form-label">School/University</label>
 <input type = "text"  class = "form-control" name = "school" >
 <label for = "department" class="form-label">Department</label>
 <input type = "text"  class = "form-control" name = "department" >
 <label for = "studentClass" class="form-label">Class</label>
 <input type = "text"  class = "form-control" name = "studentClass" >
 <label for = "section" class="form-label">Section</label>
 <input type = "text"  class = "form-control" name = "section" >
 <label for = "password" class="form-label">Password</label>
 <input type = "password"  class = "form-control" name = "password" >
 <button type = "submit" class = "btn btn-outline-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Please post your passport.use() function, For more info: http://www.passportjs.org/docs/configure/

Comment: I got it. Actually, I was initializing and creating a new session twice for User and Admin. So the Admin login was happening but the User authentication wasn't.